# Can I change the subtitle of the notification?

Tags: iphone, ios, push-notification

Every notification seems has a title, subtitle, and content.
The title is from your app's bundle display name. 
The content can be changed by the server.
My question is: Is there any way to change the subtitle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot change anything except these

- An alert message to display to the user
- A number to badge the application icon with
- A sound to play